# Reference for DB2 access from Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, db2

I am having a terrible time trying to get the most simple code to execute consistently in an Excel VBA module.

I'm just trying to assign the value of a field (column) in DB2 to a variable in the module.  I've tried the following:

Connection:

```
Dim odbcName as String
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strCmd As String

'ACME is the name of the ODBC connection I've established and verified/validated.
conn.Open("ACME")
strCmd = "SELECT UNIQUEID, MARKET, SECTOR, CLIENTID FROM PROJECTINFO WHERE UNIQUEID=1234567"

rs.Open Source:=strCmd, ActiveConnection:=conn, CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic
```

All is good to that point.  The next bit of code is:

```
If rs.EOF then 
    'Do some work to add a record if it doesn't already exist - this works fine.
Else
    Dim sqlMarket as String
    sqlMarket = rs.Fields("MARKET").Value
End If
```

I also tried:

```
    sqlMarket = rs!MARKET
```

Both of those attempts, ON THAT LINE where I was attempting to assign a local variable the contents of the MARKET field in the recordset, caused it to crash.  I mean, the entire workbook closes, then Excel reopens and tries to open the worksheets, but the module has crashed completely.

Ultimately, my intent is to check all the fields in the recordset against another set of data (in another Excel workbook), and if anything has changed, to update the DB2 recordset.  But right now, I can't even seem to LOOK AT the contents of the DB2 recordset without Excel crashing.

Can anyone offer some advice as to what I'm either doing wrong, or what I'm missing?

> Excel 365 (Version 1908) 64-bit

> IBM DB21085I 64-bit (SQL11050 with level identifier 0601010F)
> DB2 v11.5.0.1077

> Windows 10 64-bit Version1909 (Build 18363.900)

Comment: `RecordCount` is typically unreliable unless you've already moved the cursor to the end of the recordset.  A more reliable method to check for no records is to  check if EOF is true immediately after opening the recordset.

Comment: Hi, Tim. Your point is well-taken, and I've edited it to look for rs.EOF instead of getting a recordCount (and edited the example code above).  However, that doesn't change the outcome.  I successfully passed that line of the code without an error (I've got lots of breakpoints so I can see how far I get).  I'm still crashing at the point where I try to read the MARKET field from the DB2 table.

Comment: Interesting. It is actually crashing on the If rs.EOF statement. If I go back and change it to If rs.RecordCount = 0, it works.  RecordCount comes out to be -1, but I don't care.  I don't care about the counts, I'm just trying to see if there's at least one (and there should be only one) record with a uniqueID of 1234567. (That's the primary key so there should only be one).

Comment: Maybe try a different connection string.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of an ODBC connection string to be able to refer to the ODBC connection name?  I'm successfully able to add a new record to the table using that connection string.  

(I'm not trying to be a jerk here...I'm genuinely trying to learn this, so I'm asking questions that probably seem obvious to you, but aren't to me.)

Comment: I've never queried DB2 from VBA but I have worked with other databases ,and in many cases there may be multiple drivers available, which use different connection strings (I never use a system/user DNS)  https://www.connectionstrings.com/ibm-db2/  I sometimes have trouble with one variant but success with another.  Having said that I've never had a crash on just checking for EOF.

Comment: Edited to include the answers to your questions, mao.

Comment: Please add crash details (module, dll etc), may be visible in the eventvwr.  Also check client side db2diag.log.  Also you don't say if your code has an exception handler, and if and exception fires then how do you handle it?

Comment: I'm sorry to have bothered you.  I am new at this and don't know about an exception handler (I don't think I have one...that would be the On Error... right?) I don't see any crash details. All that happens is that the module window closes, Excel closes, and moments later, Excel opens and my other workbooks are re-opened.

If that's not enough information, then I'm sorry for bothering you with my question. I don't know how to get additional information.

Comment: Yes `on error` . Search in eventvwr. The idea is that if Excel crashes , to see *where* it crashed (for example, it might be in an IBM DLL) Google it.  The idea is to localise the crash (which DLL /exe), so you know who to ask next for help.  Another angle of approach is to try to make at least one of the IBM VB samples work in your environment (they are in ...\sqllib\samples\dotnet\vb for a Db2-server install on MS-Windows, and online in the Db2 Knowledge Center). Although this needs some study and time it can yield basic compatibility assurance.

Comment: I suspect your arguments of `CursorType` and `LockType` might be the issue. Try playing around with them or remove to use [ADO defaults](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/open-method-ado-recordset?view=sql-server-ver15) which usually works for simple use cases. Having connected to many databases in VBA, I rarely ever need to adjust these arguments.